# Matching regex in cases where a non-greedy match is required

Tags: python, regex

Given the following string;

```
"Hello", he said. "And now for something completely different!"(Monty Python).
```

I want to match `"And now for something completely different!"(Monty Python)`, by making reference to quotation marks and brackets. In this example, `"Hello"` should not match, as there is no bracket following the quotation mark.

A non-greedy approach looks like one way to go: `".*?"` matches `"Hello"` and `"And now for something completely different!"` separately, which is close, but if I append to this the brackets, `".*?"(.*)`, I end up matching the entire string.

That is

```
"Hello", he said. "And now for something completely different!"(Monty Python)
```

is returned.

How can I force my regex to behave the way I require? I am working in python so have the option of using lookahead/behind.

Comment: To match literal parenthesis, escape with backslash or put in class else they will open a capture group. Further I'd rather use negated class instead of the non-greedy dot which will not give you the shortest match from end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
"[^"]*"(:?\(.*\))
```

It looks for a single set of quotes (i.e. no quotes in between)
followed by the set of brackets

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
s = '"Hello", he said. "And now for something completely different!"(Monty Python).'

import re

new_data = re.findall('"(.*?)"', s)

final_data = [i for i in new_data if len(re.findall("\w+(?=!)", i)) > 0][0]
```

Output:

```
'And now for something completely different!'
```